# How do I tell Visual Studio to always expand the "Find options" group box in the Find dialog?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2015

I expand it, but it collapses sometimes, and it gets very annoying. How do I make it always be expanded?

Comment: I suspect there is none. The new in-editor experience in 2015 at least has the "advanced options" always visible in the form of toggle-buttons. And since you're likely to be at the keyboard, alt-o toggles its visibility.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio should always remember the last state of expansion of this options group box. If you can provide a set of steps that show a case where it doesn't, please drop me a line at mwthomas at Microsoft com as I'd like to take a look.

Comment: When the last option is Selection, it sticks to Selection even when nothing is selected.  So you press F3, finds something, selects it, and the next F3 fails because search is narrowed to only the text that it just matched.  Very annoying.

Comment: Hi @AlanBaljeu - we made some changes based on a lot of customer feedback, so that the scope of your search shouldn't automatically change from what you have manually selected. Many folks found automatic changing of scope to be confusing, especially when automatically changing to selection. I assume you are manually selecting the "selection" scope for your search?

Answer (score -1):

You use the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> key combination to open find options. If you want to open find dialog pop-up, you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> key combination. It is available all of Visual Studio versions.

Comment: Sorry but this is not at all what the question is about.